# How html encoding helps if my aspx page is not allowing html input from User

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have XSS Cross-Site Scripting problem in my aspx pages. When I went through solutions, I found that 70% of XSS problem will be handled by HTML encoding user inputs and saving in the database.

My Scenario:
Most of pages does not allow html input i.e ValidateRequest="True". In this case, how HTML encoding will help us ? Am I correct if I say we should do html encode only in the case of allowing html input from user ?

Suppose, html encoding of user inputs works for XSS,
Is it a good idea to do html encoding of all user input (all over application)  and saving in database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest save encoded html in database. Now the method I using don't encoded user's input. Instead of, we will encode user's input when reading from databases. You can learn about json's api, where can tell you how to encode special code.